# PantaRei.Classes.Enums.ProductTypeA1Enum.Types' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, enums, foreach

I have this bit of code that has to iterate trough a enum and make some calculations.

This is the enum

```
namespace PantaRei.Classes.Enums
{
    public class ProductTypeA1Enum
    {
        #region Reports Enum

        public enum Types
        {
            [StringValue("K01")]
            K01 = 1,
            [StringValue("K03")]
            K03 = 2,
            [StringValue("K05")]
            K05 = 3,
            [StringValue("M01")]
            M01 = 4
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is my function that takes a enum as parameter being Types the enum

```
GetData(ref secA1, ddr, ddrs, ProductTypeA1Enum.Types);
```

this is the code where I itereate through the enum

```
    public static void GetData(ref Dars secA1, Ddr ddr, Ddrs ddrs, Enum pTypes)
            {
                Array typesEnum = Enum.GetValues(pTypes.GetType());

                foreach (var types in typesEnum)
                {
                    string pType = StringEnum.GetStringValue((Enum) types);

                    secA1.OpBal = ddrs.Out.Sum(o => o.Amount);

secA1.MiCaCol +=
                ddr.Rec.Where(
                    rec =>
                    ddr.Acc.Exists(
                        acc =>
                        acc.Contract == rec.Contract && !acc.TransactionType.Equals("D9") && rec.ProductType == pType)).
                    Sum(rec => rec.Amount);
             }               
     }
```

And this is the error I get

```
PantaRei.Classes.Enums.ProductTypeA1Enum.Types' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context
```

The error comes from here

```
GetData(ref secA1, ddr, ddrs, **ProductTypeA1Enum.Types**);
```

Types is a enum, so why am I getting this error?
Any ideas?
Tks in advance
Rui Martins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do so:

```
GetData(ref secA1, ddr, ddrs, typeof(ProductTypeA1Enum.Types));
```

and

```
public static void GetData(ref Dars secA1, Ddr ddr, Ddrs ddrs, Type pTypes)
{
    Array typesEnum = Enum.GetValues(pTypes);

    // ....
}
```